# How do I get the value of WMD editor?

Tags: editor, wmd, wmd-editor

I am playing around with using the WMD Editor (http://wmd-editor.com/) in my site. I have a really simple question. When I am ready to submit the text to the server; how do I get the output of the editor?

Something like this only returns the 'actual text that user typed in the textarea'

```
    var jtext = document.getElementById('myTextarea').value;
```

I would like to get the 'output' of the editor; but I can't figure out how to do that :(

By output; I mean the 'Markdown' or 'Html' output.

Comment: How is the output different from what the user typed? Are you referring to the preview?

Comment: Output can be Markdown or Html

Comment: markdown IS what the user enters, html is what YOU turn the markdown into. wmd uses javascript to give a preview of how that markdown will look after it has been turned into html.

Comment: so does that mean that I would use javascript function to get the value of the 'preview' div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to get the contents of the preview div. Based on the demo on the wmd site, the div in question has the class wmd-preview. Not sure why it's not id'd.

In jQuery, you'd use something like:

```
$('#formname').submit(function() {
    $('#hidden_form_element').val($('.wmd-preview').html());
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. thats what I was not sure about. I was looking for a actual function call or something. So the right thing to do is to save the 'value of the textarea' and the 'value of the preview div'..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply make a textarea with the id="wmd-output", it should allows you to submit the output code